# add export functionality in custom grid (not ui grid ) Magento2

Tags: magento2, grid, export

I have created a custom admin grid using 2 tables and that is working fine.
This is not a UI grid, but a grid same as Magento 1.

Please suggest me, how can I add a export feature in that.

Comment: You could add a button somewhere, linked to a controller action which would serve an export file.

Comment: I think you can do same like Magento 1        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', __('CSV'));